# Como retornar serie de valores em Python

Tags: python

Tenho uma função que lê linha por linha um arquivo TXT em disco e formata ele extraindo só o que me interessa, ficando com uma lista assim:

```
Swi 04/11/2018 Basel Lugano 3 2 2 0
Swi 03/11/2018 Grasshopper Young Boys 0 3 0 0
Swi 04/11/2018 Luzern Zürich 2 5 1 2
Swi 04/11/2018 Sion St. Gallen 0 1 0 1
```

Qual a melhor forma de retornar essa lista? Salvar em disco (CSV ou JSON) ou tem algumas estrutura em Python que posso fazer isso?

Pois vai ser usado por outro arquivo `.py`. Lembrando que essa lista pode chegar a ter mais de 300 linhas.

Comment: Pesquise sobre gerador em Python, usando `yield`

Comment: usa json mesmo que é padrão em qualquer lugar.

Comment: Valeu Anderson Carlos Woss, para o que eu quero é isso mesmo

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Para ler um arquivo e percorrer as linhas você pode utilizar a função `open` com o gerenciador de contexto definido por `with`:

```
with open('arquivo.txt') as arquivo:
    for linha in arquivo:
        print(linha)
```

Como você precisa formatar os dados da linha, você pode fazer algo como:

```
with open('arquivo.txt') as arquivo:
    for linha in arquivo:

        # SUA LÓGICA DE FORMATAÇÃO AQUI

        print(resultado)
```

Ou, como comentado, você pode colocar isso dentro de uma função e retornar um gerador utilizando o termo `yield`:

```
def linhas_formatadas(caminho):
    with open(caminho) as arquivo:
        for linha in arquivo:

            # SUA LÓGICA DE FORMATAÇÃO AQUI

            yield resultado
```

Desta forma bastaria fazer:

```
for linha_formatada in linhas_formatadas('arquivo.txt'):
    print(linha_formatada)
```

Ou, se precisar escrever em outro arquivo, seria algo como:

```
with open('resultado.txt', 'w') as resultado:
    for linha_formatada in linhas_formatadas('arquivo.txt'):
        resultado.write(linha_formatada)
```